# Add button to kitchen sink toggle

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have created a simple function along with a shortcode, my goal is now to add a button in the sink toggle of wordpress so that the user doesn't have to type anything.

Is this hard to achieve? how can I do it.

I thought this was simple, but by looking at this tutorial http://brettterpstra.com/2010/04/17/adding-a-tinymce-button/ it seems rather complex and you have to do some hacks or something.

Is there a quicker way?